# Display large matrices in html

Tags: javascript, html, matrix, scroll

I'm trying to display a 600x600 matrix in HTML. I've tried tables, divs, Javascript libraries (scrolling) but all of them are so slow in responding to user actions.

Is there any solution for displaying these kind of matrices?

Comment: Would like to see what is been tried by you..

Comment: I've tried clusterize.js, amcharts and simple HTML tables. there's a demo here https://jsfiddle.net/bgey36mh/1/ and here https://jsfiddle.net/23k2pxje/2/

Comment: What's in this matrix?

Comment: @Brad Just a background color (4 colors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just displaying a bunch of boxes, what you need is a canvas.

You can draw boxes on it however you'd like.  It's efficient, as there's only one DOM element.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
```